# Add data in xml at certain node

Tags: php, xml

I have a nested xml file to which I want to insert elements under certain nodes. The xml structure is like:

```
<root>
    <item id="1">
        <content><name>ITEM 1</name></content>
        <item id="3">
            <content><name>ITEM 3</name></content>
            <item id="4">
                <content><name>ITEM 4</name></content>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <content><name>ITEM TWO</name></content>
    </item>
</root>
```

Suppose that I want to insert some Item as a child of item id 4, using php what would the syntax be to find the node of item 4 and append another item node in it?

Comment: Syntax depends on your code. What is your code? You can for example use `substr_replace` for example and just insert some text in there because XML is text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first use `simplexml` then search the id using `xpath`, then add the child:

```
$xml = '<root>
    <item id="1">
        <content><name>ITEM 1</name></content>
        <item id="3">
            <content><name>ITEM 3</name></content>
            <item id="4">
                <content><name>ITEM 4</name></content>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <content><name>ITEM TWO</name></content>
    </item>
</root>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); // load the XML

$id = $xml->xpath("//*[@id='4']"); // search for id=4

$item = $id[0]->addChild('item'); // add another item
$item->addAttribute('id', '5'); // add id=5
$content = $item->addChild('content', ''); // add content
$content->addChild('name', 'ITEM 5'); // add name

echo $xml->asXML(); // output
```